# Problems installing MySQL Workbench on Centos

Tags: mysql, installation, centos, mysql-workbench

I'm installing MySQL Workbench and I'm getting this message:

```
checking for python2.6... yes
checking for python2.7... no
checking for Python libraries... -L/usr/lib64 -lpython2.6
checking for CAIRO... configure: error: Package requirements (cairo >= 1.5.12 gl) were not met:

No package 'gl' found

 Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
 installed software in a non-standard prefix.

 Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CAIRO_CFLAGS
and CAIRO_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

`mesa-libGL-devel` solved this particular dependency for me. I'm using Fedora 17, fwiw.